# MySQL - Select Max Date

Tags: mysql

I has a table below

```
id  Title datetime       Details
---|----- |------------|--------|---------
1  | AAA  | 28/03/2009 | AAAAA
2  | BBB  | 26/03/2009 | BBBBB
3  | CCC  | 27/03/2009 | CCCCC
```

I want to display only 2 record with the latest date

The record need display as below

```
id  Title datetime       Details
---|----- |------------|--------|---------
1  | AAA  | 28/03/2009 | AAAAA
3  | CCC  | 27/03/2009 | CCCCC
```

Any idea how I can do that?  Please help

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: is the datatype of datetime `VARCHAR`? since the value are not formatted as `yyyy/MM/dd`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
          SELECT DISTINCT dateTime
          FROM   tableName
          ORDER  BY STR_TO_DATE(datetime, '%d/%m/%Y')  DESC
          LIMIT  2
        ) b ON a.datetime = b.datetime
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f053e/4)

For better performance, create an `INDEX` on column `datetime` and if possible, fix the values of your dates into `yyyy/MM/dd` and change it's data type to `DATETIME` so you won't have any casting from string to date as it may decrease the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by datetime desc, and then use LIMIT.

If `datetime` field is stored as a date (or as a datetime):

```
SELECT   yourtable.*
FROM     yourtable
ORDER BY yourtable.datetime desc
LIMIT    2
```

if `datetime` it is stored as a varchar instead, you can just order by this:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(datetime, '%d/%m/%Y') desc
```

(if there are more than two records with the last dates, this will show just 2 rows, I am not sure this really what you are after).